# What is the correct method for appending to a text file in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I wanted to append data to a file containing the data:-

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I wrote the following code :-

```
import java.io.*;
public class AddtoFile
{
    public void main()
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("Student.txt",true);
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Phone numbers");
                String phone=br.readLine();
                bw.write(phone);
                bw.newLine();
            }
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

But even after giving the required input, when I open the file I find that nothing has been appended to the previous data.Please do point out if there is any mistake in my logic because my compiler has reported no syntactical error in the code.
For a little more information if (there is some mistake in the code of writing to a file as well)

```
import java.io.*;
class WritetoFile
 {
     void main()throws IOException
     {
         BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         try
         {
             FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("Student.txt");
             BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
             for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
             {
                 System.out.println("Enter your name");
                 String name=br.readLine();
                 bw.write(name);
                 bw.newLine();
                }
                bw.close();
                fw.close();
            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        }
    }
```

(Please do tell me because I have got no such help from JavaDocs as well)

Comment: How are you running this code? The signature for your `main` method isn't suitable for a normal Java entry point...

Comment: @JonSkeet is right (as always...). Are you sure your program gets executed at all?

Comment: Well @Axel it does ask for the necessary inputs if thats what you are asking for

Comment: @Axel My code now works with the String[] args.So thanks to all the persons who answered to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` method signature is wrong. It should have `String[]` arguments to run the code. In order to append to a file, you can modify the `FileWriter` instantiation as follows:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Student.txt", true);   // true means append
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `FileWriter(File, boolean)` constructor - `FileWriter(String, boolean)` should work just as well.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, I missed that :) Updated.

Comment: @TheViper As mentioned in the comments, the `new File` contructor is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Files#append()` and in the OpenOption argument give it `StandardOpenOptions.APPEND`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
public class AddtoFile
{
    public void main(String arg[])
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try
        {
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("Student.txt",true);
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Phone numbers");
                String phone=br.readLine();
                phone=phone+"\n";
                fw.write(phone);
            }
            fw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    }
}
```

This should work fine.

Reference Link: http://learn2geek.com/file-handling-java/

Comment: Is there no need for a BufferedWriter? @AnkitNanglia

Comment: Nope FileWriter write method will do the needfull